# I am creating calendar subscribe external .ics format.This ics file contains events and to-dos

Tags: calendar, icalendar, webcal

I am creating calendar subscribe external .ics format(webcal link support).This ics file contains events and to-dos. 
Only sunbird desktop calendar adds events and todos both.

I also tried on Microsoft outlook calendar (calendar.live.com).It adds both events and todos.

Google calendar, Yahoo calendar and Outlook(2010) doesn't add todos from the subscribed url.

It is a bug in my code or google,yahoo and outlook does not support todos from external subscribe ics format url.

Format of the ics file is :

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID;X-RICAL-TZSOURCE=TZINFO:-//com.denhaven2/NONSGML ri_cal gem//EN 
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20130627T213000Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20130626T183000Z
ATTENDEE: abcd
DESCRIPTION:
SUMMARY:twesdasd event
ORGANIZER:abcd@gmail.com
LOCATION:
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VTODO
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20130627T182959Z
DESCRIPTION:
SUMMARY:testing task delete
END:VTODO
BEGIN:VTODO
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20130626T182959Z
DESCRIPTION:
SUMMARY:testing document task...
END:VTODO
BEGIN:VTODO
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20130620T182959Z
DESCRIPTION:
SUMMARY:testing task attachment
END:VTODO
BEGIN:VTODO
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20130621T182959Z
DESCRIPTION:
SUMMARY:test123
END:VTODO
BEGIN:VTODO
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20130623T182959Z
DESCRIPTION:
SUMMARY:sdfsa fads fdsafdsafdsafdsfdsfdsfasfds
END:VTODO
BEGIN:VTODO
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20130622T182959Z
DESCRIPTION:
SUMMARY:task on testDoc2 .txt
END:VTODO
END:VCALENDAR

Comment: And your code looks like ... what? Maybe you can share it with us so we can help you.